# Project structure issue in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

it seems that creating a new spring boot starter project is adding some files and packages that i dont need such as Spring elements and jax-ws web services
[image]

any idea on how to fix this best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional elements are being added to the project explorer view by specific project natures and facets. The `Spring Elements` node, for example, is being provided by the Spring Tools for every project that has the `Spring Nature` enabled. The deployment descriptor thing (which is indeed totally useless for a Spring Boot project) seems to come from the project facet for dynamic web projects being enabled in your projects (for whatever reason).

Instead of changing the config for each project you could also use the `Package Explorer` view, which does not contain these additional nodes at all. This is the one that I am using all the time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ,i was on the **project explorer**  view when i suppose to be on the **package explorer**